# Change date color of specific date

Tags: android, calendar

I have used https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView calendar component in my project. I want to change the color of some particular dates in calendar. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: May be you would need to wait. It has already mentioned in feature enhancement list: https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView/issues/166